# ImportError when using Spyder and Ipython in a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, ipython, spyder

I create a virtualev (~/ENV) in Ubuntu 12.10, using the --system-site-packages option, where I install using pip sphynx and pyzmq (necessary to install spyder) and then spyder itself and then ipython (also tried in reversed order). Spyder works fine without Ipython, but when I try to run it after installing Ipython, it gives an ImportError:

```
zdk1g12@walrus:~$ source ENV/bin/activate
(ENV)zdk1g12@walrus:~$ spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zdk1g12/ENV/bin/spyder", line 3, in <module>
    start_app.main()
  File "/home/zdk1g12/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/start_app.py", line 64, in main
    from spyderlib import spyder
  File "/home/zdk1g12/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 95, in <module>
    from spyderlib.plugins.inspector import ObjectInspector
  File "/home/zdk1g12/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/plugins/inspector.py", line 36, in <module>
    from spyderlib.widgets.ipython import IPythonControlWidget
  File "/home/zdk1g12/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/ipython.py", line 12, in <module>
    from IPython.frontend.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget
  File "/home/zdk1g12/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/IPython.py", line 12, in <module>
    from IPython.frontend.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget
ImportError: No module named frontend.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget
```

When I try `from spyderlib import spyder` from the console, it gives the same error. However, if in the next line (same console, just after the error) I do:

```
from IPython.frontend.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget
```

...it works just fine!

Some details:

```
In [3]: import spyderlib; spyderlib.__version__
Out[3]: '2.2.0rc'
In [6]: import IPython; IPython.__version__
Out[6]: '0.13.2'
In [8]: import sys; sys.executable
Out[8]: '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/bin/python'

In [9]: import sys; sys.path
Out[9]: 
['/home/zdk1g12/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/utils/external',
 '',
 '',
 '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/bin',
 '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/home/zdk1g12/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Ipython works ok, also the qtconsole.

Comment: I wonder if you have multiple versions of ipython installed one of them ipython qtconsole and one of them without it ???

Comment: @dusual no, just one version installed with pip, which has everything.